# Why is this mov causing a SIGSEGV

Tags: nginx, segmentation-fault, coredump, luajit

Could anybody please point me in the right direction why is this mov instruction causing a segfault? This is what it looks like when the core file gets loaded into gdb...

```
(gdb) x/8i $rip-4
0x198f6f79: nop
0x198f6f7a: nop
0x198f6f7b: nop
0x198f6f7c: nop
=> 0x198f6f7d:  mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x401bb410,0x2a
0x198f6f88: mov    r8d,DWORD PTR ds:0x401bb4b4
0x198f6f90: movsd  xmm7,QWORD PTR [r8+0x30]
0x198f6f96: cvttsd2si eax,xmm7
```

0x401bb410 seems like a valid address

```
(gdb) x/1w 0x401bb410
0x401bb410: 0x00000022
(gdb) x/1wd 0x401bb410
0x401bb410: 34
```

DS is set to zeroes

```
(gdb) i r
rax            0xc  12
rbx            0x4125bf70   1092992880
rcx            0x4125c1c0   1092993472
rdx            0x9  9
rsi            0x4125bf70   1092992880
rdi            0xfffffffb411f0580   -20382284416
rbp            0x8  0x8
rsp            0x7ffc4acc78f0   0x7ffc4acc78f0
r8             0x426bf980   1114372480
r9             0x10 16
r10            0x10 16
r11            0x51ad0c 5352716
r12            0x426bf980   1114372480
r13            0x7fade525af58   140384850521944
r14            0x8  8
r15            0xc  12
rip            0x198f6f7d   0x198f6f7d
eflags         0x10297  [ CF PF AF SF IF RF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

And address in $rip seems to be marked as CODE, so there should be no NX, right?

```
(gdb) maintenance info sections
Core file:
`/root/core_1478876914_15894', file type elf64-x86-64.
...
[17]     0x198e0000->0x19900000 at 0x00853000: load5 ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
```

Am I missing something obvious here? `ngx_http_lua_run_thread` calls `lua_resume(orig_coctx->co, nrets)` which passes execution to LuaJIT compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer`

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000198f6f7d in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000040d90798 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000051c7b1 in lj_vm_inshook ()
#3  0x00000000004daada in ngx_http_lua_run_thread (L=0xfffffffb411f0580, L@entry=0x401bb378, r=0x4125bf70, r@entry=0x7fade4f03710, ctx=0x9, ctx@entry=0x7fade525af30, nrets=0)
at ../modules/lua-nginx-module/src/ngx_http_lua_util.c:1005
...
```

Using [openresty-gdb-utils](https://github.com/openresty/openresty-gdb-utils) gives me LuaJIT trace number

```
(gdb) ltracebymcode $rip
(GCtrace*)0x431168b8 (trace #42)
machine code start addr: 0x198f6f7d
machine code end addr: 0x198f7155
```

And dumps the IR code for the trace (which I do not understand at all yet)

```
(gdb) lir 42
(GCtrace*)0x431168b8
IR count: 36

---- TRACE 42 start 3/? mymodules_handlers.lua:97
---- TRACE 42 IR
....              SNAP   #0   [ ---- ]
0001 rax   >  int SLOAD  #7    CRI
0002       >  int LE     0001  +2147483646
0003 rbp      int SLOAD  #6    CI
0004 r12   >  tab SLOAD  #2    T
0005          int FLOAD  0004  tab.hmask
0006       >  int EQ     0005  +15 
0007 r11      p32 FLOAD  0004  tab.node
0008       >  p32 HREFK  0007  "features" @6
0009 rdx   >  tab HLOAD  0008
0010 rsi      int FLOAD  0009  tab.asize
0011       >  int ULE    0010  0003
0012 xmm0     num CONV   0003  num.int
0013 r10      p32 HREF   0009  0012
0014       >  tru HLOAD  0013
0015 r9    >  tab SLOAD  #3    T
0016          int FLOAD  0015  tab.asize
0017       >  p32 ABC    0016  0001
0018 rcx      p32 FLOAD  0015  tab.array
0019          p32 AREF   0018  0003
0020       >  fun ALOAD  0019
0021       >  tab SLOAD  #1    T
0022       >  fun EQ     0020  mymodules_features.lua:208
0023 rbp    + int ADD    0003  +1  
....              SNAP   #1   [ ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- true ]
0024       >  int LE     0023  0001
....              SNAP   #2   [ ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- true 0023 0001 ---- 0023 ]
0025 ------------ LOOP ------------
0026       >  int UGE    0023  0010
0027 xmm7     num CONV   0023  num.int
0028 rbx      p32 HREF   0009  0027
0029       >  tru HLOAD  0028
0030          p32 AREF   0018  0023
0031       >  fun ALOAD  0030
0032       >  fun EQ     0031  mymodules_features.lua:208
0033 rbp    + int ADD    0023  +1  
....              SNAP   #3   [ ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- true ]
0034       >  int LE     0033  0001
0035 rbp      int PHI    0023  0033
```

Any advice is highly appreciated and more information can be provided, I've been stuck with segfaults like this for days.

Thanks a lot champs!

Comment: Currently I am in touch with Peter Cawley and Igor Ehrlich (both having commits in LuaJIT code) and we are trying to locate the issue. More can be found over [here](https://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/SIGSEGV-in-LuaJIT-21-VM)